# What is the Difference between Texture and Image?

Tags: computer-vision, image-processing, image-segmentation, image-compression

I am beginner in the image processing

I want to know what is difference between Texture and Image? or whether they are same? can anyone explain it.

Also,if i want to do texture segmentation,can i use same algorithms as applicable to the image segmentation?

Comment: Could you share the context you encountered it?

Comment: @Drazick sir, in one book on image processing i read that that texture is the repetitive pattern in spatial domain with characteristics such as brightness, color, shape, size, etc. but it is similar with the image also... is it? also i want to do texture segmentation, i can use same algorithms as applicable to the image segmentation....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An image (2D) is the projection of a natural scene or man made drawing on to a plane. The output of an optical sensor when displayed is an image.

Texture is a picture created by repeating a basic element called 'texel'. The texel can be a natural image or an artificial one.

The edge detection algorithms works on matrices. So if it is a normal image or texture image, you can do in the same way.

In texture images, recognizing the texel makes the rest of processing easy. Because you need to work on a smaller sized matrix.